# Replace all NaN values with value from other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0],
                   [3, 4, np.nan, 1],
                   [np.nan, np.nan, 5, np.nan],
                   [np.nan, 3, np.nan, 4]],
                  columns=list('ABCD'))
```

I want to do a `ffill()` on column B with `df["B"].ffill(inplace=True)` which results in the following df:

```
     A    B    C    D
0  NaN  2.0  NaN  0.0
1  3.0  4.0  NaN  1.0
2  NaN  4.0  5.0  NaN
3  NaN  3.0  NaN  4.0
```

Now I want to replace all NaN values with their corresponding value from column B. The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) states that you can give `fillna()` a Series, so I tried `df.fillna(df["B"], inplace=True)`. This results in the exact same dataframe as above.

However, if I put in a simple value (e.g. `df.fillna(0, inplace=True)`, then it does work:

```
     A    B    C    D
0  0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0
1  3.0  4.0  0.0  1.0
2  0.0  4.0  5.0  0.0
3  0.0  3.0  0.0  4.0
```

The funny thing is that the `fillna()` does seem to work with a Series as `value` parameter when operated on another Series object. For example, `df["A"].fillna(df["B"], inplace=True)` results in:

```
     A    B   C  D
0  2.0  2.0 NaN  0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1
2  4.0  4.0 NaN  5
3  3.0  3.0 NaN  4
```

My real dataframe has a lot of columns and I would hate to manually `fillna()` all of them. Am I overlooking something here? Didn't I understand the docs correctly perhaps?

**EDIT** I have clarified my example in such a way that 'ffill' with axis=1 does not work for me. In reality, my dataframe has many, many columns (hundreds) and I am looking for a way to not have to explicitly mention all the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the axis to 1 (columns):

```
df = df.ffill(1).bfill(1)
```

If you need to specify the columns, you can do something like this:

```
df[["B","C"]] = df[["B","C"]].ffill(1)
```

---

EDIT:
Since you need something more general and `df.fillna(df.B, axis = 1)` is not implemented yet, you can try with:

```
df = df.T.fillna(df.B).T
```

Or, equivalently:

```
df.T.fillna(df.B, inplace=True)
```

This works because the indices of `df.B` coincides with the columns of `df.T` so pandas will know how to replace it. From the docs:

> value: scalar, dict, Series, or DataFrame.
> Value to use to fill holes (e.g. 0), alternately a dict/Series/DataFrame of values specifying which value to use for each index (for a Series) **or column (for a DataFrame)**. Values not in the dict/Series/DataFrame will not be filled. This value cannot be a list.

So, for example, the `NaN` in column `0` at row `A` (in `df.T`) will be replaced for the value with index `0` in `df.B`.

Comment: Hm, this works on this minimal reproducible example but I want the value from a specific column, not just the one before with a non NaN value. In reality I have many columns that might or might not have a value, I really need the value from column B

Comment: @Pablo C, IMHO, just fyi here, your recent edit has made your 1st answer identical as mine, just fyi please I had posted it before, commenting here so no confusions :) cheers

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Sorry! it wasn't on purpose I just realized it was better

Comment: Thanks for the update @PabloC! Your edit doesn't seem to produce the correct results; I assume `T` needs to be replaced with a column name (e.g. `A`)? If so, I know that this method works on Series, but I need it to work on the entire dataframe. The doc's say its possible, might it just be a bug?

Comment: @JarroVGIT the T means transpose, please keep it as T and try again

Comment: It produces the same result (e.g. no effect). :(

Comment: @JarroVGIT what are you trying? I mean the line of code

Comment: I have it working (whoohoo), the trailing `.T` in your EDIT was not working and I had to add `inplace=True`: `df.T.fillna(df.B, inplace=True)` I really do not understand why this works though? PS if you edit your answer I will accept it.

Comment: @JarroVGIT Nice! `df.fillna(something, inplace=True)` means the df will be replaced by the new one, it is equivalent to `df = df.fillna(something)`

Comment: But why is the transposing working here? Don't get me wrong, I am happy that it works, but I just can't see the logic of transposing a dataframe (which in itself returns a dataframe) and then give a Series object to fillna which is not the correct lenght (because now rows are columns and my B series remains the same shape).

Comment: @JarroVGIT I was going to explain it here but I decided to edit my answer instead. I hope it helps

Comment: @PabloC: many thanks for updating your post. Am a bit ashamed that I had read past the part in the documentation that you have bolded, but now it is clear to me. I am going to do some testing on timing; my dataset is several million rows long so I might be better off by looping over all Series rather than transposing twice. Anyway, fantastic explanation for which many thanks!

Comment: @JarroVGIT it would be really nice to know what is faster :)

Comment: @PabloC Well it was quite a huge difference haha. The transpose option took 2min44sec on a (7867620, 7) df which takes 375MB of memory. The for loop option took a whopping 2 seconds, so I am going with the latter lol